# Custom JPA Bean Validator with parameters similiar to @Size

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation

I am looking to implement a JPA Bean Validator for a Annotation similiar to the `@Size` Annotation, so allowing parameters `min` and `max` on the annotation. I have been looking through the documentation and various examples but couldn't find an implementation that would allow multiple parameters on the Annotation.

Currently my code looks like this

```
@Target({ FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CapacityImpl.class)
public @interface Capacity {

    String message() default "Capacity not in valid Range";

    // Required by validation runtime
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

}
```

The final Annotation should look like this `@Capacity(min=19, max=40)`

```
public class CapacityImpl implements ConstraintValidator<Capacity, Integer> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(Capacity capacity) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Integer integer, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So my question is how do I have to change this interface and class to actually allow the parameters min and max on the Annotation, so that I then can validate the value of the field with those paramter values

Comment: FWIW this is not the JPA API, it is the Bean Validation API, different spec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add them to your annotation definition:

```
public @interface Capacity {

    String message() default "Capacity not in valid Range";

    // Required by validation runtime
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

    int min();
    int max();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public @interface Capacity {

    String message() default "Capacity not in valid Range";

    // Required by validation runtime
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

    int min();
    int max();
}
```

the validator class

```
@Component
public class CapacityValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Capacity, String> {
    private  int min;
    private  int max;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Capacity constraintAnnotation){
        this.min = constraintAnnotation.min();
        this.max = constraintAnnotation.max();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String capacity, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        //validate logic here e.g
       if(capacity > this.min){
         return true;
        }
    }
}
```